# What's the Python equivalent of on.exit() in R

Tags: python, r

In R, there's an `on.exit()` function that records the expression given as its argument as needing to be executed when the current function exits (either naturally or as the result of an error), which is useful for resetting graphical parameters or performing other cleanup actions. For example:

```
f <- function(...) {
    ... # some operations that the function performs
    on.exit(...) # operations to perform right before the function exits
}
```

I wonder if there's any Python equivalents that can achieve similar effects?

Edit: here's what I wanted to do in Python:

I have been writing a script that performs GUI automation using the `pyautogui` module.

There's a `pyautogui.PAUSE` variable that controls the PAUSE between each operation(keyboard or mouse), and the default is 0.1 seconds.

I am new to python and I found that the global/local scoping rules that I used to know do not apply to this variable. When the value is changed inside a function, it affects the behaviors of other operations outside the function. For example:

```
import pyautogui

print(pyautogui.PAUSE) # default is 0.1 secs

def f():
    pyautogui.PAUSE = 0 # simply change the value inside a function

f() # call the function

print(pyautogui.PAUSE) # now becomes 0 sec
```

So I would like to know how to restore the default value when the function exits(either naturally or as the result of an error).

Comment: You can use `try:`/`finally:` to make sure code in the `finally:` block is always run, regardless of any errors in the try block.

Comment: Either `with ...` or `try ... finally ...` might be able to do what you need. Please provide an example of your python code where you think you need this so that someone can suggest the right approach.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you need [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html)
something like this could help (example from link)

```py
def goodbye(name, adjective):
    print('Goodbye, %s, it was %s to meet you.' % (name, adjective))

import atexit
atexit.register(goodbye, 'Donny', 'nice')

# or:
atexit.register(goodbye, adjective='nice', name='Donny')
```

Comment: The name sounds similar, but `on.exit` registers a handler for when the current *function* ends, not for program exit.